# How to Identify a Job is using Stored Procedure or SSIS Package using query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Thanks for looking into my post.

I am looking for a method/query to identify a SQL Server job is using stored procedure or SSIS package in the SQL Server Agent.

Comment: So what is your question here exactly? You've told us what your goal is, but not asked any thing. What have you tried, and what isn't working, or where have you got stuck?

Comment: I tried to open each job and find the stored procedure but there are lot of jobs so, hard to find by this process. Is there any easy way to find using simple query?